# jQuery exported file showing error while opening in Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have exported an excel file using jQuery from the html table. Though it exported very well, when opening it using Excel showing me below error

> The file format and extension of 'download.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I know we can resolve it either by creating excel at server side or by disabling the [extension hardening](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning-on-opening-excel-workbook-from-a-web-site-2/) on system registry. But both of these options are out of scope for me because of limited resources available and I need to fix it client side only.

Sample excel output:

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>My Worksheet</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Class</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name 1</td>
<td>Class 1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't, since the ".xls" file is actually consists of HTML and CSS. That is why it shows the error. Won't you consider using ".CSV" instead?

Comment: you mean instead of exporting html tags, export in csv format ?

Comment: yes. But the downside of this is CSV won't carry any of your CSS, just plain text. Since the program will just export out the data in comma-delimited form, and if you're using MS Office, Excel automatically recognize CSV files as its own.

Comment: Thanks @Hardyson for your suggestions. I think it will not be possible to export excel without any styles.